# What can I add to the reasoning/development of this exercise?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, definite-integrals, proof-explanation

The exercises reads
$$F(x) = \int_0^x e^{-t^2}\ \text{d}t$$
Say if $F(-1)$ is less, greater or equal than zero.

**My solution**

First of all I see $f(t) = e^{-t^2}$ is a continuous function and it's a positive function. Hence all its primitives are increasing functions. Since
$$f'(t) = -2te^{-t^2}$$ we observe that $f'(t) > 0$ for $t < 0$ and since we work in $[-1, 0]$, $f(t)$ is monotone increasing function.
This means $f(-1) < f(0)$ and hence $\int_0^{-1} f(t)\ \text{d}t = F(-1) - F(0)$, but $F(-1) < F(0)$ and hence we have $F(-1) - F(0) < 0$

So $F(-1)$ is negative.

Another way to see this is that in $[-1, 0]$ we have $e^{-x^2} \geq e^{-1}$ because $f$ is increasing. integrating this inequality between $0$ and $-1$ we get

$$\int_0^{-1} e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x \geq \int_0^{-1} e^{-1}\ \text{d}x$$

$$\int_{-1}^0 e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x \leq  \dfrac{1}{e}$$

Yet this doesn't show me $F(-1) < 0$.

What can I add to the reasoning in order to show $F(-1)< 0$ in other ways? Or simply making "my ways" more rigorous?

Is there someone who can provide an actual answer or are you all here to play riddles?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141398/discussion-on-question-by-numb3rs-what-can-i-add-to-the-reasoning-development-of).

Answer (score 1):

The function $F$ is strictly increasing because $F’\left(x\right)=e^{-x^2}>0$ for all $x$ (by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).

Since $F\left(0\right)=0$ we have $F\left(-1\right)<0$.

Answer (score 0):

for  $x\in(-\infty,0)$

$f'(x)>0$

so , in your second way put $\int_{-1}^{0}{f(x)dx}>0$ as $f(x)>0$ for all $x$.
and reverse the limits of integral to get $F(-1)<0$